# Keystonejs 5 - FieldType Array?

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

Is there a possibility to adding fields as array?

Currently i just found the possibility to create none-array fields.

Comment: I have exactly same question. I'm trying to store an array of strings and I can't do it. It seems like v4 has a way to do so with Types.TextArray, and I don't understand why they take it away in v5. Mind boggling.